# Let sshd only accept freenx clients

Tags: ssh, openssh, nomachine-nx, sshd

I installed freeNX (remote GUI access), which is based on sshd service.
It means all users who can access freeNX should be assigned a ssh-enabled account.

But I don't want part/all of these users directly access the sshd service via any ssh client.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know freeNX, but if it don't need a shell access, just SSH, you can put `/bin/false` as the shell for each users in your `/etc/passwd` file.

For this you must modify the last entry on each correspondent line (usually `/bin/bash`) to `/bin/false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your ssh server to accept only specific users & groups by modifying /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
    AllowUsers admin
    AllowGroups freenx_users
```

Remember to restart your ssh server after you make the change.

```
    /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

More details about AllowUsers and AllowGroups see the man page:

```
    man sshd_config
```